# All-in-1 decentralized project management git+tickets+wiki

Tags: git, svn, project-management, wiki

I am looking for some type of command line software, like git but with all the other tools necessary to manage projects.

These days we all use version control system plus "some type of hosted issue trackers or wiki" to manage our projects. Instead of doing that I want to use all-in-1 decentralized solution.

Comment: This is nowhere near enough a useful description. You'd need to add much, much more detail.  However, I'm afraid this is probably off-topic here either way

Comment: This does not seem off-topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839777/svn-project-management-wiki-todo-list

Comment: Not off topic.  Falls clearly under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one answer, but it has its own version control system built-in.

"Fossil SCM offers decentralized source control, tickets and a wiki: http://www.fossil-scm.org/"

P.S. : I love how so down votes like crazy ,even if there are tons of same type of questions with lots of up votes, just because they do not get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Also, check out veracity. New kid on the block, but has bug tracking and project management built in.

http://veracity-scm.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using  tools that work together and each do one thing well rather than a tool that attempts to do everything.  That way, you're less locked in to your tool choice: if you find that one of the tools isn't doing it for you, you can easily swap it out and continue to use the other tools you're used to.

There are a few decentralised project tracking tools that build upon distributed version control for their storage.  I myself have written one: https://github.com/npryce/deft.

I also did a quick review of other tools in the same space that I found: https://github.com/npryce/deft/wiki/Other-Distributed-Issue-Trackers.  This may well be out of date now.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codebasehq.com/ may be what you are after. It also has support for more version control systems than just Git, which is handy if you are working with a client steadfast on Subversion for example.

Comment: is that a software/solution ?, or is it just another git/svn hosting + hosted issues and wiki?

Comment: Aah, I just read your reference to command line and decentralized systems! In that case, the latter :)